# GLSL to Cg fragment shader

Tags: opengl, glsl, cg, bump-map

I have found very useful resource on the [Swiftless website](http://www.swiftless.com/) on OpenGL.

Unfortunately, I cannot manage to adapt a GLSL fragment shader to my project, which uses Cg. Here it is:

```
uniform sampler2D color_texture;  
uniform sampler2D normal_texture;  

void main() {  

// Extract the normal from the normal map  
vec3 normal = normalize(texture2D(normal_texture, gl_TexCoord[0].st).rgb * 2.0 - 1.0);  

// Determine where the light is positioned (this can be set however you like)  
vec3 light_pos = normalize(vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.5));  

// Calculate the lighting diffuse value  
float diffuse = max(dot(normal, light_pos), 0.0);  

vec3 color = diffuse * texture2D(color_texture, gl_TexCoord[0].st).rgb;  

// Set the output color of our current pixel  
gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);  
}
```

I have tried something:

```
struct fsOutput {
    vec4 color : COLOR;
};

uniform sampler2D detailTexture : TEXUNIT0;
uniform sampler2D bumpTexture : TEXUNIT1;

fsOutput FS_Main(float2 detailCoords : TEXCOORD0,
            float2 bumpCoords: TEXCOORD1)
{

    fsOutput fragm;

    float4 anorm = tex2D(bumpTexture, bumpCoords);
    vec3 normal = normalize(anorm.rgb * 2.0f - 1.0f);
    vec3 light_pos = normalize(vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.5f));
    float diffuse = max(dot(normal, light_pos), 0.0);
    vec3 color = diffuse * texture2D(detailTexture, detailCoords).rgb;
    fragm.color = vec4(color, 1.0f);
    return fragm;
}
```

But it doesn't work. To debug, I have a function that catches Cg errors, and my program breaks at this point. I have identified the two texture IDs in the main program.
Can you suggest any improvement for this Cg shader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried compiling it from the command-line as follows:

```
cgc -profile glslf -entry FS_Main test.cg
```

This gave the following error output:

```
test.cg
test.cg(18) : error C1066: invalid type in type constructor
test.cg(18) : error C1010: expression left of ."rgb" is not a struct
```

This immediately highlights the fact that you used `texture2D` on line 18 instead of the correct Cg function `tex2D`.  Fixing this error makes it compile correctly.

In the future, you should probably use the `cgGetLastListing` function when `cgGetError` returns `CG_COMPILER_ERROR`.  This will allow you to print out the error listing in your application, which makes your shaders easier to debug.

On another note, you use `vec3` and `vec4` on various occasions.  While the Cg compiler seems to accept this, the correct types are `float3` and `float4`, I believe.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the command line method - but did you really compile the SECOND shader? The second is my Cg try, the first is the original GLSL. I have already put tex2D. The program crashes before it can display any error :(

Comment: Yes, I compiled the second shader, the Cg one.  The second shader still contains one mention of `texture2D` as well as a mention of `tex2D`.

Comment: Aye Sir... You are totally right. The shader seems to compile fine now but the program keeps crashing for some reason. I will look this "cgc" command up to help me debug in the future. Thanks again

Comment: I should note that using `cgc` is not a substitution for proper use of the Cg Runtime's error checking API.  All that `cgc` does can be done (and should be done) using simple API calls such as `cgGetLastListing`.  It was merely a convenient way for me to see which errors it would produce, which would have equally been printed by a call to `cgGetLastListing`.