# GLSL to Cg: why is the effect different?

Tags: opengl, c++, shaders, glsl, cg

With reference to [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/80078/glsl-to-cg-fragment-shader/80080?noredirect=1#comment143702_80080), where I was trying to make the shader compile, I am now trying to make an effect appear.
The effect can be shown here, through a GLSL shader:

[image]

But when I use the equivalent Cg shader, the result becomes this:

[image]

Using the same images (color map + normal map) and the same code (except the way to retrieve variables).

Here is the original GLSL shader;

```
uniform sampler2D color_texture;  
uniform sampler2D normal_texture;  

void main() {  
    // Extract the normal from the normal map  
vec3 normal = normalize(texture2D(normal_texture, gl_TexCoord[0].st).rgb * 2.0 - 1.0);  

// Determine where the light is positioned (this can be set however you like)  
vec3 light_pos = normalize(vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.5));  

// Calculate the lighting diffuse value  
float diffuse = max(dot(normal, light_pos), 0.0);  

vec3 color = diffuse * texture2D(color_texture, gl_TexCoord[0].st).rgb;  

// Set the output color of our current pixel  
gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);  
}
```

And here is the Cg shader I wrote;

```
struct fsOutput {
    float4 color : COLOR;
};

uniform sampler2D color_texture : TEXUNIT0; 
uniform sampler2D normal_texture : TEXUNIT1;

fsOutput FS_Main(float2 colorCoords : TEXCOORD0,
            float2 normalCoords: TEXCOORD1)
{

    fsOutput fragm;


    float4 anorm = tex2D(normal_texture, normalCoords);
    float3 normal = normalize(anorm.rgb * 2.0f - 1.0f);
    float3 light_pos = normalize(float3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.5f));
    float diffuse = max(dot(normal, light_pos), 0.0);
    float3 color = diffuse * tex2D(color_texture, colorCoords).rgb;
    fragm.color = float4(color,1.0f);
    return fragm;
}
```

Please let me know if something needs to be changed in order to obtain the effect, or if you need the C++ code.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. Edited (the problem remains the same).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shader was fine. But when I tried to use other shaders I realized what was wrong.

It was the C++ code that was lacking lines (rrr!! This is the reason why I hate shaders! It's so complicated to make a link in your head between every line you write in one file and what must be written in the other for it to be recognized!).

In the display function, I had:

```
[clearing + loading identity matrix]

cgGLBindProgram(VertexProgram);
cgGLBindProgram(FragmentProgram);

[buffers swapping]
```

The very important thing that was missing before binding was:

```
cgGLEnableProfile(VertexProfile);
cgGLEnableProfile(FragmentProfile);
```

Only then the shader effect is displayed proprerly.
Simple mistakes make worst time wastes!

Answer (score 2):

They are not equivalent. In the GLSL shader you use the same texture coordinate for your diffuse and normal map (`gl_TexCoord[0]`). In the CG shader you use separate ones (`TEXCOORD0` and `TEXCOORD1`, which is presumably not set).

Comment: Really? I tried to find an equivalent to "gl_TexCoord[0]" but could only find this! Can you help with a suggestion?

Comment: Yes, TEXCOORD0 is the equivalent for gl_TexCoord[0], which you are using as texture coordinates for both the diffuse and normal map in the GLSL shader. But you use TEXCOORD1 in the CG shader, which would be gl_TexCoord[1] in a GLSL shader. You could just use `colorCoords` in the CG shader for both your diffuse and normal map lookup and it should work. Or you can supply a separate set of texture coordinates just for the normal map.

Comment: Sorry but that won't work (colorCoords for both). Still the same result.

Comment: Okay, then it's probably not that. What about the normal map itself? Is its content correct, is it bound to the corrent texture state? Try setting `color` to just the .rgb values of `anorm`. Does the result look like your normal map?

Comment: Absolutely not! The result is still the same! And yes, the normal map is correct because it works wonderful in GLSL as I said. The shader is correctly bound because if I remove some key word it won't execute at all.